# Will I have enough points to unlock all skills and enough material to unlock all weapon upgrades?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

I am playing through the campaign and have been unlocking skills and weapon upgrades as I go along.   I am only 25% through the game, but I would like to know if I will have enough points to unlock all skills and enough material to unlock all weapon upgrades.

If not, I will then go for specific skills and weapon upgrades in further tiers that I want (instead of arbitrarily unlocking everything).

Comment: My forst point of call when I have these questions is to check if there is an achievement for it. Its worth mentioning that there is no achievement I could find for "maxxing out lara", but there is kne for maxxing a category

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to unlock all skills and upgrade all weapons. I have played ~40 hours, have achieved 100% completion, and have all skills unlocked. I haven't grinded enough after completing the campaign to get enough salvage to upgrade all of my weapons (this is the only resource I'm consistently running low on). I have upgraded all of my bows and pistols, but the upgrades for the rifles and shotguns cost a lot of salvage.

But if you keep fast traveling between the Soviet Installation and

> The Lost City

after completing the campaign, you should be able to gather enough salvage to upgrade all of your weapons.

Answer (score 0):

No.  I finished the game, played some more in the exploration mode (91% complete) and I still don't have all the skills or weapon upgrades.